# Why can't different abi's be linked together?

Tags: c++, abi

I see as a beginner that compilation units need to be the same ABI's in order to be able to be linked. I also read about how c++ commitee is hesitant to make ABI breaking changes to avoid making it hard to link against precompiled code with source unavailable. Is it not possible to somehow add some kind of translation code, or to alter old binaries somehow, such that they still link?

Comment: Not directly, but yes, you can using [thunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) or other magics. [Middleware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware) often has to deal with stuff like that.

Comment: Every layer you add adds perfomance penalties.

Comment: Well, yes, it is *possible*, as Dúthomhas noted.   There are, however, costs of doing so (e.g. runtime performance impacts, maintenance burden - for implementers of compilers and possibly operating systems as the amount of translation code increases).  Such costs affect timeliness of updates of compilers to newer standards, as well as end users of software built using new and old compilers - hence the committee's caution in introducing ABI changes.   Bear in mind that "don't pay for what is not used" is a core philosophy of the standardisation effort.

Answer (score 0):

In C types such as floats, ints and chars etc, are always the same, just x number of bits in memory. Names are also not mangled in anyway so function names have to be completely different to be unique.

In C++ the classes and functions are mangled into symbols. How this mangling is done changes from compiler to compiler. So Microsoft Visual C++ might mangle a class with all the floats, then ints, and then chars, then methods. Let's call this method A.

But in GNU C++ it might work back to front compared to this. So methods, then chars, then ints and then floats. This will produce a different mangle to the Ms Compiler. Method B.

Let's say the exe is wrote in Ms Compiler and the DLL in GNU C++. You app is importing method A and expects that to be the data, but what it receives is method B and doesn't understand it and crashes.

That's what it means when the ABI's aren't standard.

Comment: It is more than that. It is also things like how objects are organized in memory and v-table layout and memory pool stores and so on.

Comment: You explain why different ABI's are not compatible. However, that's not the question: the OP is asking why there isn't a mechanism to link them together, like a translator or other middleware.

Comment: Because that is why there is no middleware. It answers his question, sorry you don't like that.